# How to implement Catmull Clark Subdivision algorithm in OpenGL ES Shader

Tags: opengl-es, shader

I've implemented simple Catmull Clark subdivision algorithm to run on a mesh. But it runs on CPU, and after only few iterations it becomes too compute intensive. I figured one way to solve this problem is to rewrite it in Shader language and then run it on GPU.

Are there any examples of the same?

Comment: Keep in mind that shaders are still quite limited in their abilities and it's definitely not always a way to solve a performance-related problem by just magically "rewriting it in shader language". And for this special problem you won't find any simple shader being able to solve it (at least not on ES hardware). There maybe some fancy GPGPU shader to do catmull-clark subdivision, but this either uses some very complicated texture-based data-structure (I will look if I find it, have seen it once) or a very special remeshing (like geometry images).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you would need geometry shader (tesselation) features on your GPU for that - to emit/create new vertices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_shader

i am not aware of consumer hardware, supporting OpenGL ES, at the moment that is capable of that.

Answer (score 0):

Catmull–Clark is done prior to the face(s) being broken up into primitives(points, lines, triangles).  For example the Catmull–Clark wikipedia page shows a cube being changed into a sphere, if done with triangle shaped faces instead of square the resulting shape would not be a sphere.   This may be possible in Vulkan using Patches, but I don't see how.  To do Catmull–Clark faces(unlike patches) need to have vertices they share and i don't see how to specify this relationship.  Other than to search for vertices that are equal, thus nullifying any performance gains.